# Diango matching a string with a regex field

Tags: django, django-models, django-3.2

In `django`, if we have a regex and look for a rows whose a field is matching with a regex, it will be something like this:

```
MyAudience.objects.filter(email__iregex=f'^({'|'.join(emails)})$')
```

But what if I want to do it the other way?

Let's say I have a string:

```
email = 'abc@example.com'
```

and in my model `AudienceFilter`, I have a field `pattern`. This column keeps the regex for the model. I want to find with patterns do match my string? How can I do that?

```
AudienceFilter.objects.filter(pattern__?????=email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the value as an alias, and then annotate:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

AudienceFilter.objects.alias(email=Value(email)).filter(
    email__iregex=F('pattern')
)
```